# Scaling an html5 canvas and div overlay

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, scaling

I've found a lot of useful information already here for this particular problem, but as yet can't quite solve it. As the title suggests, the issue is scaling an html5 canvas, and a div overlaying that canvas, while maintaining aspect ratio for both. The div in this case being a UI on top of the canvas.

Currently, the canvas scaling seems fine. However, scaling the UI proportionally has proven troublesome. The following appears to work in a few tests on Chrome, Android, and Safari on iPad. It's not so effective on Firefox, IE or Opera.

In essence, I'm using a canvas scaling approach, and attempting to scale the UI using CSS zoom with the same ratio. In the following example, I'm also applying the vendor specific prefixes to show the effect in Firefox and Opera. Without these, the scaling doesn't apply.

There are a few instances where scrollbars are added, but those can be removed with overflow: hidden. I haven't applied that in this fiddle so the effect is more obvious.

Markup:

```
<body>
    <div id='wrapper'>
        <canvas id='main' width="800px" height="600px"></canvas>
        <div id='ui'>
            <div id='close' class='ui-button'></div>
            <div id='next' class='ui-button'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
            margin: 0;
        }
        #wrapper{
            position: relative;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 800px;
            height: 600px;
        }
        canvas{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #ui{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1000;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
        .ui-button{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            background-color: #000;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
        #next{
            top: auto;
            bottom: 0;
        }
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
            var width = 800, height = 600;
            var ctx = $('#main')[0].getContext('2d');

            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function(){  
                ctx.drawImage(img , 0, 0);
            };  
            img.src = 'http://visualparadox.com/images/photos/skya12800.jpg';

            var scaleContent = function(){
                var scale = Math.min(window.innerHeight/height, window.innerWidth/width); //initial values

                var w = scale * width;
                var h = scale * height;

                $('#wrapper').css({width: w + "px", height: h + "px"});
                $('#ui').css({zoom: scale, "-moz-transform": "scale(" + scale + ")", , "-o-transform": "scale(" + scale + ")"});
            }

            window.addEventListener('resize', scaleContent, false);

            scaleContent();
        });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0sm284qz/1/

Any ideas how to correct this behaviour? Also, if there are any general suggestions for a better approach I'd be interested to hear them.

Many thanks,

Baps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior in firefox is a result of the scaling being applied to the divs current width/height which is set to 100% of its container.  As the container is shrunk, the scale of the child will be some percent of that.

One fix for this would be to set the child to a fixed width and then scale it from there.  You will also need to set the transform-origin to 0 0 (top, left):

```
#ui{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

If the linked fiddle, I used 800 x 600: [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0sm284qz/3/)

Ultimately, I don't think scaling will provide the best result for you.  Instead, I'd suggest changing your layout to use relative height, width and position.

**Using relative height/width**

If your aspect ratio is a constant 800x600 you can change your CSS for `.ui-button` to use a width of 10% (80px/800px) and a height of 13.33% (80px/600px) rather than adjusting the scale during window resize:

```
.ui-button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 10%;
    height: 13.33%;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

This will provide a similar end result to the scaling you were doing before.

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0sm284qz/4/)

Comment: That's looking better! Do you have an example or reference of using relative height/width/position that maintains aspect ratio?

Comment: @Baps I've added a relative size example.  I prefer the second approach given the example you've provided.. YMMV :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give an example, dc5. I see what you're getting at here. I'm not entirely sure this will work for more complex content in the UI; e.g. text, images and background images etc. Seems fine for this simple example though.

Comment: Also use "pointer-events:none;" on the div if you want to click through to the canvas :)